# UITableview "UITableViewAutomaticDimension" Not working in Nested Table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I face one problem in **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**. I have one `UITablviewCell` With `UITableView`. And in cell table, I have one Label and image in a nested table cell. Like below.

```
<br>
TableView 
<br>---> Cell*1
<br>-------->Tableview*2
<br>-----------> Cell*2
<br>--------------->Lable + Image
```

For example:- If an image is available than cell*2 height should be `image(150 height) + Label height`. OR If not then cell*2 size Label Height.

And `Cell*1` should be `Tableview*2` height (here table scroll is disabled)

Here the problem is `Cell*2` height not set according to Nested `Tableview*2` height.

Please send help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **heightForRowAtIndexPath** in the inner tableview and return 180 (150+30--for label) OR 30 for label only